# Symbol is considered to be an identifier, not an operator

Tags: swift

I wanted to implement a currency operator for use in my software that takes a Double and returns a Currency type for more precise calculations.

The code for a custom operator basically looks somewhat like this. Please disregard the obvious dropping of precision and therefore useless operator in this form.

```
postfix operator £ { }
postfix func £(number: Double) -> Int {
    return Int(number)
}

3.50£ // returns Int(3)
```

This works fine in Swift. Interestingly enough though I run into errors when trying exactly the same with a € symbol.

```
postfix operator € { }
postfix func €(number: Double) -> Int {
    return Int(number)
}
```

This produces the error `'€' is considered to be an identifier, not an operator`. I don't follow why this isn't allowed though.

Comment: Download the Swift book and check the exact syntax for identifiers and operators. If "€" is an identifier and "£" is an operator it's because the syntax of the Swift language says so. PS. Be very careful trying to use "clever" code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The characters allowed in a custom operator is listed in [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/operator), and € is not one of these. (You could also find corresponding [Lexer code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/8802d6d52afcac225e9d460e3441c88f4e52b8f2/include/swift/AST/Identifier.h#L87-L121)).

The main difference between the two currency symbols is that **£** (and also **¢** and **¥**) are in the Latin-1 supplement block (U+0080 – U+00FF), while **€** is in the Currency Symbols block (U+20A0 – U+20CF), and for some reason the Swift language considers these as identifier-like instead of operator-like.

- The first character of an operator must be one of these:

  - `.`
  - `/=-+!*%<>&|^~?`
  - Latin-1 supplement: `¡¢£¤¥¦§©«¬®°±¶»¿×÷`
  - General Punctuation: `‖‗†‡•‣․‥…‧‰‱′″‴‵‶‷‸‹›※‼‽‾⁁⁂⁃⁄⁅⁆⁇⁈⁉⁊⁋⁌⁍⁎⁏⁐⁑⁒⁓⁕⁖⁗⁘⁙⁚⁛⁜⁝⁞`
  - Arrows (U+2190 – U+21FF): Whole block
  - Mathematical operators (U+2200 – U+22FF): Whole block
  - Miscellaneous Technical (U+2300 – U+23FF): Whole block
  - Box Drawing (U+2500 – U+257F): Whole block
  - Block Elements (U+2580 – U+259F): Whole block
  - Geometric Shapes (U+25A0 – U+25FF): Whole block
  - Miscellaneous Symbols (U+2600 – U+26FF): Whole block
  - Dingbats (U+2700 – U+27BF): All *except* the circled numbers ❶–❿,➀–➉,➊–➓
  - Miscellaneous Math Symbols-A (U+27C0 – U+27EF): Whole block
  - Supplemental Arrows-A (U+27F0 – U+27FF): Whole block
  - Braille Patterns (U+2800 – U+28FF): Whole block
  - Supplemental Arrows-B (U+2900 – U+297F): Whole block
  - Miscellaneous Math Symbols-B (U+2980 – U+29FF): Whole block
  - Supplemental Math Operators (U+2A00 – U+2AFF): Whole block
  - Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows (U+2B00 – U+2BFF): Whole block
  - Supplemental Punctuation (U+2E00 – U+2E7F): Whole block
  - CJK Symbols and Punctuation: `、。〃〈〉《》「」『』【】〒〓〔〕〖〗〘〙〚〛〜〝〞〟〠〡〢〣〤〥〦〧〨〩〪〭〮〯〫〬〰`
- The rest of the operator can also be one of these characters:

  - Combining Diacritical Marks (U+0300 – U+036F): Whole block
  - Combining Diacritical Marks Supplemental (U+1DC0 – U+1DFF): Whole block
  - Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols (U+20D0 – U+20FF): Whole block
  - Variation Selectors (U+FE00 – U+FE0F): Whole block
  - Combining Half Marks (U+FE20 – U+FE2F): Whole block
  - Variation Selectors Supplement (U+E0100 – U+E01FF): Whole block
- A `.` can appear at the rest of an operator only if the first character is a `.`.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

In Swift, we cannot use identifiers to overload an operator. (It's operator overloading not identifier overloading ;) )

```
postfix operator a {} //A is an identifier. Compiler throws the Same error
```

For some reason `€` is an identifier while `£` is a valid operator!

```
var € = 35 //Compiles
var £ = 35 //Doesn't compile because
```

The unicode of `€` is `U+20AC` which falls between `U+2070 – U+20CF` is a valid identifier. The unicode of `£` is `U+00A3` which is not a valid identifier. (Note that  `U+00A8, U+00AA, U+00AD, U+00AF` are all valid identifiers!)

You can find out about valid identifiers and operators [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html)