# Is it possible to use kotlin infix functions and swift infix operators the same way (with equal naming)?

Tags: swift, function, infix-operator

I have a infix function in kotlin that can be called like this:

```
"name" eq "XY"
```

Now I am trying to do the same in swift. I already thought I could do it like the following, but that doesn't seem to be working:

```
class Condition {
    var left: String = ""
    var center: String = ""
    var right: String = ""
    
    init(left: String, center: String, right: String) {
        self.left = left
        self.center = center
        self.right = "\(right)"
    }
    
    var toString: String {
        return "\(left) \(center) \(right)"
    }
}

func eq(field: String, value: String) -> Condition {
    return Condition(left: field, center: "=", right: value)
}

infix operator eq
func eq(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Condition {
    return eq(field: lhs, value: rhs)
}

print(("name" eq "XY").toString)
```

error: 'eq' is considered to be an identifier, not an operator
infix operator eq

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbol is considered to be an identifier, not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204271/symbol-is-considered-to-be-an-identifier-not-an-operator)

Comment: I have already seen that question, yes. That might explain the error I get. I cannot use those symbols in kotlin. So is the answer that I can NOT do it the same way in both languages and need to come up with something else?

Comment: what is Condition? A custom object?

Comment: Yes, the Condition class just returns me the string concatenated (added it to the question). @TusharSharma

Comment: and eq operator overloading is meant to do the same thing?

Comment: With the equal sign, yes. I'd build this with multiple operators later (all using the Condition class). This will be used in a SQLite Query at the end. @TusharSharma

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not finding any solution, I will do it like the following:
I won't use kotlin infix functions. On Swift-side I'll write String extensions.
This way I can use the function on both sides like this:

```
("name".eq("XY")).toString
```

If anybody knows something cleaner, let me know :)

Comment: Why not use a custom infix operator but with a valid name?

Comment: I think in this case the name wouldn't be valid in kotlin anymore and I need the naming to be equal for both swift and kotlin. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Yeah you're not going to be able to `eq` as it's also an identifier name. Your solution is probably the best you're going to get!